# IDE for HTML/CSS/JS/Java on Android Tablet possible?

Tags: android, ide

**Edit:** Found a couple of great IDE's:

- [AIDE - Android Java IDE (Great IDE)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&feature=search_result)
- [Webmaster's HTML Editor Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.welant.webmaster.DEMO&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS53ZWxhbnQud2VibWFzdGVyLkRFTU8iXQ..)
- [DroidEdit (Free Version)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmFvci5kcm9pZGVkaXQiXQ..)

So after some research on google, i was not able to find any Apps for android to assist me in coding HTML/CSS/JS.. In other words, no IDE App that we can load up that supports some sort of intellisense or autocomplete, tag highlighting.

I understand we have online IDE's that we can use for things like this, ***but is there a possible reason for not one developer to try an IDE for the Google Play Store?*

> Edit: For some reason my tablet did not display any of the IDE's i
>   showed above, there are plenty out there which is why i put a list
>   above for who ever is looking for something similar.

I feel that it will work well; a perfect and very powerful example of this is "[Autodesk's SketchBook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adsk.sketchbookhd&hl=en)" which ofcourse, has nothing to do with software development, but my point is - their innovation in their user interface shows. They implemented Maya's huge menu system which uses the spacebar to popup a fancy UI circle thats simple to access and provides most tools quickly.

Something similar to Autodesk's approach will work very well as a Web Development IDE.

So, bottom line:

**1)** Do you know of any current/work-in-progress IDE's for Android tablets?

**2)** Any recommendations that will benefit a Web Developer wanting to try content 
creation on a 7" Tablet!? Crazy i know ;0)

**3)** Please list your most useful tools for the android that would be relevant to this question.

Thank you!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adsk.sketchbookhd&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Have you checked [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&feature=nav_other#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDYsImNvbS5zcGFydGFjdXNyZXguc3BhcnRhY3VzaWRlIl0.)?

Comment: That's interesting, i found one after clicking on the link you provided.. Which makes me wonder, if there a better way to find apps for android. I don't think their Play store is well lay out. Hard to find something unless you try searching for it.

Comment: I completely agree with you. The lesser known apps don't seem to be indexed well at all. I find this surprising since Google's regular web search engine is fantastic!

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I don't know why i did not see this IDE or the others that were tag along as recommended once i opened up the "Terminal IDE" link when i did my own search in the tablet. I hope google implements a better system for us to find apps. I had an IPad and i had a better experience finding programs via their app-store, very well organized.

Comment: I agree, Apple's app store search engine allows users to find apps more easily. However, I personally found Terminal IDE when I was looking for something similar a while back by searching "google play ide" on google.com. In the future it'd probably be easier just to do that.

Comment: This app is not available in the play store

Answer (score 2):

Check out my app - [Android Web Developer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd). I think it's exactly what are you looking for.

Comment: Looks beautiful, thank you for this. I will be checking it out shorty!